# How to show pop-up window animation frame (starting from a grid cell rect)

Tags: windows, delphi, animation, rect

I'm using BDS 2007...

When a user double-clicks a grid cell in our application we display a modal window over the grid. I developed the routine below to draw an animation frame on the grid. It enlarges by drawing and erasing a frame in steps, before the window shows (much like the Windows UI animation). The same routine gets called again (with bExpand=False) after the window closes, to give the UI effect of the window imploding back into the grid cell.

This routine worked fine in Windows XP but misbehaves when Aero is enabled (works fine in Windows 7 *without* Aero). The animation frame redraws slowly...even if I comment out the DelayMSecs line (which is just a loop that calls Sleep(0) repeatedly until the iDelay number of milliseconds has passed).

And when the routine is called again (after the window closes) it is equally slow, plus leaves a frame on the screen, plus there's a ghost image of the (now closed) window left in place, essentially alpha-blended with the normal display contents of the grid.

Most of the routine's code calculates the changing rectangle size. Only three lines do the actual draw & erase of the animation rect:

```
          ScreenCanvas.Rectangle( r );               //draw frame
          SysStuff.DelayMSecs( iDelay );             //
          ScreenCanvas.Rectangle( r );               //pmXOR pen ...erase frame
```

Any ideas on why this is slow under Aero, or what I need to change?

```
procedure T_fmExplore.AnimateRects(ASourceRect, ADestRect: TRect; bExpand:
    boolean; bAdjustSourceForFrame: boolean = True);
{ Draw animation frames in steps, for transition from ASourceRect to ADestRect.
    bExpand:  determines whether the animation rect is expanding or contracting.
    bAdjustSourceForFrame:  resize the animation rect smaller for the window frame. }
const
  MINSTEPS = 10;               //Min redraws of the animation rect (frame)
  MAXSTEPS = 20;               //30 was too many, too slow
  MAXDELAY = 100;              //Delay between drawing each rect frame
  MINDELAY = 1;
var
  iSteps: integer;
  DeltaHt: Integer;               //Rect size chg for each redraw of animation window
  DeltaWidth: Integer;
  DeltaTop :  integer;            //Origin change for each redraw
  DeltaLeft :  integer;
  TgtWidth, TgtHt: Integer;
  iTemp: Integer;
  iDelay: integer;
  r : TRect;                    //Animation frame's rect
  ScreenCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  r := ASourceRect;
  TgtWidth :=   ADestRect.Right - ADestRect.Left;         //Target rect's Width
  TgtHt :=      ADestRect.Bottom - ADestRect.Top;         //Target rect's Height
      //Initially Deltas hold total chg in Width & Height
  DeltaWidth := TgtWidth - (r.Right - r.Left);            //TgtWidth - old width
  DeltaHt :=    TgtHt - (r.Bottom - r.Top);
      //For smooth animation we adjust number of iSteps & Delay relative to the window area.
      //Larger window = more iSteps and shorter Delay between drawing each step.
  iSteps := Max( DeltaWidth * DeltaHt div 6500, MINSTEPS );
  iSteps := Min( iSteps, MAXSTEPS );
      //Now convert Deltas to the delta in window rect size
  DeltaWidth := DeltaWidth div iSteps;
  DeltaHt :=    DeltaHt div iSteps;
  DeltaTop :=   (ADestRect.Top - ASourceRect.Top) div iSteps;
  DeltaLeft :=  (ADestRect.Left - ASourceRect.Left) div iSteps;
  iDelay := Max( MAXDELAY div iSteps, MINDELAY );
  ScreenCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  try
    ScreenCanvas.Handle := GetDC( 0 );              //Desktop
    try
      with ScreenCanvas do begin
        Pen.Color := clWhite;   //Do NOT use clBlack with pmXOR mode: with (r=0, g=0, b=0) there are no bytes to XOR.
        Pen.Mode := pmXOR;      //MUST use pmXOR pen, so 2nd Rectangle call (see below) erases what we drew.
        Pen.Style := psSolid;
        Pen.Width := 3;         //Thin line.  Was: Pen.Width := GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME);
        Brush.Style := bsClear;
        if bAdjustSourceForFrame then
          InflateRect(ASourceRect, -Pen.Width, -Pen.Width);
        repeat
          iTemp := (r.Bottom - r.Top) + DeltaHt;        //Height
          if (bExpand and (iTemp > TgtHt)) or (not bExpand and (iTemp < TgtHt)) then begin
            r.Top := ADestRect.Top;
            r.Bottom := Top + TgtHt;
          end else begin
            r.Top := r.Top + DeltaTop;            //Assign Top first...Bottom is calc'd from it
            r.Bottom := r.Top + iTemp;
          end;

          iTemp := (r.Right - r.Left) + DeltaWidth;     //Width
          if (bExpand and (iTemp > TgtWidth)) or (not bExpand and (iTemp < TgtWidth)) then begin
            r.Left := r.Left + DeltaLeft;
            r.Right := r.Left + TgtWidth;
          end else begin
            r.Left := r.Left + DeltaLeft;         //Assign Left first...Right is calc'd from it
            r.Right := r.Left + iTemp;
          end;

          ScreenCanvas.Rectangle( r );               //draw frame
          SysStuff.DelayMSecs( iDelay );             //
          ScreenCanvas.Rectangle( r );               //pmXOR pen ...erase frame

        until (r.Right - r.Left = TgtWidth) and (r.Bottom - r.Top = TgtHt);
      end;
    finally
      ReleaseDC( 0, ScreenCanvas.Handle );
      ScreenCanvas.Handle := 0;
    end;
  finally
    ScreenCanvas.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Unless you find some hacky way to get access to the underlying Direct3D surface that DWM uses, you're out of luck with this approach. I would just take a screenshot of the screen and draw the animation on this (unfortunately static at that time) screenshot.

Comment: P.S. there's a typo in your code, `r.Bottom := Top + TgtHt;` won't compile. Wasn't that meant to be `r.Bottom := R.Top + TgtHt;` ?

Comment: @TLama: Yes, a typo. I had converted from using a **with** statement just before I posted, so I wouldn't get yelled at.<g>  By the way, I had begun to look at the Windows Animation Manager stuff this morning, but it looks like a lot of overkill just to draw a few rectangles on the screen.

Comment: Windows Animation API is cool, as long as you provide it a fast renderer, which is your current problem actually. The way how Aero renders the desktop [`is different`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729480%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#composited_window_management) and renders by using Direct3D surface to which the DWM does not provide access so I don't think you can do much against that except rendering elsewhere (e.g. on your window). I guess that their developers did not count with people drawing on the desktop canvas itself and focused on its real content - windows.

Comment: Have you considered the built-in [`DrawAnimatedRects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162475.aspx)? It should display an animated window frame (including title bar) rather than a simple outline.

Comment: @RobKennedy:  I believe considered and then discarded DrawAnimatedRects as a possibility back when I wrote this. But I'll give it another look. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark, besides, if we look at your approach from a higher perspective, you are actually drawing to a foreign (desktop) window out of sync of its `WM_PAINT` message arrival (if the dektop window acts as a *common* window), which is techically wrong.

Comment: @RobKennedy: It turns that DrawAnimatedRects has the *same problem* as my own code...it only shows an animation when Aero is disabled! (I'm surprised.)